# How to automatically sort a QTreeWidget column?

Tags: c++, qt, sorting, qtreewidget

I'm using a `QTreeWidget` to display some simple items. I've set the list sortable by `.setSortingEnabled(true)` calling. In this way, the list is sorted only when the user press the title column, and not automatically whenever new item is inserted.

Is there a way to force the automatic sorting in a specified column without calling `.sortItems(column)` at every item insertion?
If it's possible, I would highlight the whole sorted column.

Comment: I don't see what difference (except for few lines of code) there is between manual and automatic sorting. Is there a reason why you can't do the sort upon item insertion?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To do this, use [QTreeView::setSortingEnabled()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtreeview.html#sortingEnabled-prop) and [QTreeView::sortByColumn](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtreeview.html#sortByColumn).  Just remember to turn this on /after/ you initially populate the widget, and turn it off again /before/ doing any bulk updates for efficiency.